# Adding text to multiples rows in word with a single bookmark

Tags: c#, openxml

Is it possible to add several rows with the help of Bookmarks and openXML to a word document?

We have a worddocument that serves as a report template.
In that template we need to add several transaction rows.
The problem is that the number of rows aren't static. It could be 0, 1 or 42 for example.

In the current template (which we can change) we have added 3 bookmarks
TransactionPart, TransactionPart2 and TransactionPart3.
The tree transactionparts forms a singel row with three different datacontent (ID, Description, Amount)

If we have just one transaction row we have no problem adding the data to those bookmarks, but what do we do when we should add row two? There are no bookmarks for more rows.

Is there a smart way of doing this?

Or should we change the worddocument so that the rows end up in a table? Would that solve the problem in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put a single bookmark lets call it "transactions" inside a 3 coloumn table.
Like this
[image: tablelayout]

When you know the design of the table, but not the number of rows you'll be needing the simplest way is to add a row for each line of data you have.

You could accomplish that with a code like this

```
//make some data.
            List<String[]> data = new List<string[]>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                data.Add(new String[] {"this","is","sparta" });
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("yourDocument.docx", true))
                {
                    var mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                    var bookmarks = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>();
                    var bookmark = 
                        from n in bookmarks 
                        where n.Name == "transactions" 
                        select n;

                    OpenXmlElement elem = bookmark.First().Parent;
                    //isolate tabel
                    while (!(elem is DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table))
                        elem = elem.Parent;
                    var table = elem; //found
                    //save the row you wanna copy in each time you have data.
                    var oldRow = elem.Elements<TableRow>().Last();
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow row = (TableRow)oldRow.Clone();
                    //remove old row
                    elem.RemoveChild<TableRow>(oldRow);
                    foreach (String[] s in data)
                    {
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow newrow = (TableRow)row.Clone();
                        var cells = newrow.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell>();
                        //we know we have 3 cells
                        for(int i = 0; i < cells.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            var c = cells.ElementAt(i);
                            var run = c.Elements<Paragraph>().First().Elements<Run>().First();
                            var text = run.Elements<Text>().First();
                            text.Text = s[i];
                        }
                        table.AppendChild(newrow);
                    }
                }
```

You end up with this

[image: final table]

I've tested this code on a pretty basic document and know it works.
Good luck and let me know if I can clarify further.